# Inequality with derivative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How Can I prove that if $u(x,y)\in C^3(\overline\Omega$). Then 
$$
|\nabla u|^2\leq u.
$$

I already tried to consider the function $g(u)=|\nabla u|^2-u$ and derive but it still fails.

Comment: This looks like nonsense. For starters, $u$ could be negative everywhere.

Comment: In fact, but we to consider only $u\geq0.$

Comment: So take $u(x,y)=x$ on the unit square. You need to give *all* appropriate hypotheses in the posting.